# Extract functor in Coq to OCaml using Extraction mechanism of Coq

Tags: ocaml, coq, coq-extraction

I have a function `PolyInterpretation` (http://color.inria.fr/doc/CoLoR.PolyInt.APolyInt.html)

```
Definition PolyInterpretation := forall f : Sig, poly (arity f).
```

and a module signature `TPolyInt`(http://color.inria.fr/doc/CoLoR.PolyInt.APolyInt_MA.html)

```
Module Type TPolyInt.
  Parameter sig : Signature.
  Parameter trsInt : PolyInterpretation sig.
  Parameter trsInt_wm : PolyWeakMonotone trsInt.
End TPolyInt.

Module PolyInt (Export PI : TPolyInt).
```

Then in my file `rainbow.v`, I define a module `TPolyInt_imp` purpose to use functor `PolyInt`

```
Module TPolyInt_imp.
 Variable arity : symbol -> nat.
 Variable l : list {g : symbol & poly (arity f).
 Definition sig := Sig arity.
 Definition trsInt f := fun_of_pairs_list f l.
 ...
End TPolyInt_imp.
```

Where `fun_of_pairs_list` has type: `forall f: Cpf0.symbol, list {g : symbol & poly (arity g)} -> poly (arity f)`

Then I define a module `P`:

```
Module Export P := PolyInt TPolyInt_imp.
```

The `Coq`proof assistant accepted the definition `P` above.

Then I used extraction to extract to `OCaml`.

I write it in another file: `extraction.v`

```
Extraction Language Ocaml.
Set Extraction Optimize.
Set Extraction AccessOpaque.
Separate Extraction rainbow.P.
```

It works fine.

Here is the code after the extraction

```
module TPolyInt_imp = 
 struct 
  (** val arity : symbol -> int **)
  
  let arity =
    failwith "AXIOM TO BE REALIZED"
  
  (** val l : (symbol, poly) sigT list **)
  
  let l =
    failwith "AXIOM TO BE REALIZED"
  
  (** val coq_sig : coq_Signature **)
  
  let coq_sig =
    coq_Sig arity
  
  (** val trsInt : symbol -> poly **)
  
  let trsInt f =
    fun_of_pairs_list arity f l
 end

module P = PolyInt(TPolyInt_imp)
```

Because inside the functor `TPolyInt_imp` they included `Variable` and generate the `failwith AXIOM`then I decided to define a new signature to contain all those variables.

```
Module Type Arity.
 Variable arity : symbol -> nat.
 Variable l : list {g : symbol & poly (arity g)}.
End Arity.
```

Then define a new functor taking (`Arity`) as a parameter. And inside this functor I define module `TPolyInt_imp` (like `TPolyInt_imp` before).

```
Module S (Import A: Arity).

  Module TPolyInt_imp.
    Definition sig := Sig arity.
    Definition trsInt f := fun_of_pairs_list f l.
    ...
  End TPolyInt_imp.

  Module P := PolyInt TPolyInt_imp.

End S.
```

Then I use the extraction to extract it to `Ocaml`.

```
Extraction Language Ocaml.
Set Extraction Optimize.
Set Extraction AccessOpaque.
Separate Extraction S.
```

Then I got an error saying that:

```
Error: Signature mismatch:
       ...
       Values do not match:
         val trsInt : Cpf0.symbol -> Polynom.poly
       is not included in
         val trsInt : APolyInt.coq_PolyInterpretation
       File "rainbow.ml", line 534, characters 8-14: Actual declaration
```

The code after the extraction:

```
module type Arity = 
 sig 
  val arity : symbol -> int
  val l : (symbol, poly) sigT list
 end

module S = 
 functor (A:Arity) ->
 struct 
  module TPolyInt_imp = 
   struct 
    (** val coq_sig : coq_Signature **)
    
    let coq_sig =
      coq_Sig A.arity
    
    (** val trsInt : symbol -> poly **)
    
    let trsInt f =
      fun_of_pairs_list A.arity f A.l
   end
  
  module P = PolyInt(TPolyInt_imp)
```

What is wrong with the extraction? and the reason why they have this error? How can I correct my code that I can get the success compile after the extraction?

Also I do not want to define a new module that implement the signature `Arity`.

I am so sorry for my code lacking of type and not able to compile. I am trying to give the idea of my problem.

Comment: What is the definition of `Sig` (used in your `TPolyInt_imp` module)?

Comment: Record Signature : Type := mkSignature {
  symbol :> Type;
  beq_symb : symbol -> symbol -> bool;
  beq_symb_ok : forall x y, beq_symb x y = true <-> x = y
}. Definition Sig (arity:symbol -> nat) := mkSignature arity beq_symbol_ok. (http://color.inria.fr/doc/CoLoR.Term.Varyadic.VSignature.html#Signature)

Comment: OK... How was the definition of `PolyInterpretation` extracted? It seems that erasure is causing the two types not to be unifiable anymore, even though that shouldn't happen...

Comment: type coq_PolyInterpretation = symbol -> poly; module type TPolyInt = 
 sig 
  val coq_sig : coq_Signature
  val trsInt : coq_PolyInterpretation
 end